# Underscore Snippet

Tags: sublimetext2, code-snippets

Note: I have Emmet installed onto Sublime Text 2

In my workflow I have a lot of projects were I have to put underscores in between every word in a sentence. Is there a snippet I could build in sublime text 2 to do this for me with a tab trigger of some selected text?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use Find and Replace. Highlight the text you want and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> (or <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> on Mac) to open the Find and Replace box. Click the right-hand button on the top row to choose `In Selection`, and maybe the bottom right-hand button for `Highlight matches` if you want. Type a space in the `Find What:` box, an underscore in the `Replace With:` box, and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> to Replace All (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> to Replace one at a time).

---

To use a snippet, do the following. Select `Tools -> New Snippet...` and put the following in it:

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[${SELECTION/\s/_/g}]]></content>
</snippet>
```

Save it as `Packages/User/replace_space_with_underscore.sublime-snippet`. Then, open `Preferences -> Key Bindings - User` and put in the following:

```json
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+-"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": { "name": "Packages/User/replace_space_with_underscore.sublime-snippet" } }
]
```

(If you already have custom key bindings, just put in `{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+-"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": { "name": "Packages/User/replace_space_with_underscore.sublime-snippet" } }` at the end, and remember to put a `,` after the one just above it.)

Save both files, and now you can highlight whatever text you want, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd>, and replace the whitespace with underscores. If you just want spaces (no tabs or newlines), replace the "`\s`" with "`\`" (backslash space). This regex will replace multiple spaces with the same number of underscores. It gets a bit more complicated if you only want exactly one space, or exactly one underscore, but it's doable.

Comment: Can this be done multiple times from a shortcut? Or do I need to do this process for every section I want to change?

Comment: @SethUrquhart - see my edit above. You can go the snippet route, but if you like the Find and Replace version, the field values should stay the same, so to run it multiple times you can just hit `Ctrl-H, Ctrl-Alt-Enter` whenever you need to. Personally, though, I'd take the time to set up the snippet, as it's just a single key combo.

Comment: I'm using Emmet, will this affect it in any way, sorry I should have mentioned that on my question.

Comment: @SethUrquhart It shouldn't, but you can test beforehand by hitting `ctrl+shift+-` and seeing if it does anything. If not, you should be good. If it does, just change it to another key combination.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create a snippet with this functionality by using regular expression–based [snippet substitutions](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html?highlight=snippets#substitutions). The only code you need is this:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
${SELECTION/\s/_/g}
]]></content>
</snippet>
```

You can then select a sentence, run this snippet from the command palette, and all of the spaces within will be substituted with underscores. You might have to adjust the regex (currently just `\s`) depending on what amount of whitespace you want to replace.

Comment: I'm using Emmet, will this affect it in any way, sorry I should have mentioned that on my question.

Comment: @SethUrquhart Emmet shouldn't break simple snippet functionality, no.  I don't know that Emmet can do anything similar without the need for a new snippet, but to me, using something like this would be the simpler solution regardless.